# how to find the cumulative density function

Tags: probability, statistics

Consider $$f(x)=3x^{-4} \qquad \mbox{on} \qquad x\geq 1.$$

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable on $x\geq 1$. Find the cumulative distribution $F(x)$ for $X$.

I know that CDF for a continuous random variable $X$ is defined for every $x$ by $$F(x) = P(X\leq x) =\int_{-\infty}^x f(y) dy $$

I used this definition and I got $-\frac{1}{x^3}$ which I believe I've gotten wrong because when I get the probability of a particular interval say, $1 \leq x \leq 2$, I get a negative answer which is really wrong. I still am confused of the definition especially on the integral part. Where does $f(y) dy$ coming from?

Comment: cdf abbreviates cumulative *distribution* function.

Comment: There's no such thing as a cumulative density function: the word "cumulative" contradicts the word "density".  "Cumulative" implies it's an _extensive_ quantity and "density implies it's an _intensive_ quantity. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 1):

the integral's lower limit is $1$ not $-\infty$. With that you will get the correct cdf.

Comment: oh okay. since the interval is $x \geq 1$ then $-\infty$ is replaced by $-1$ . thanks a lot!

Comment: The point is that you do want to integrate $f(y)$ from $-\infty$ to $x$, but $f(y) =3 y^{-4}$  only for $y \ge 1$; for $y < 1$, $f(y) = 0$.  So (if $x \ge 1$)
$$ \int_{-\infty}^x f(y)\; dy = \int_{-\infty}^1 0\; dy + \int_1^x 3y^{-4}\; dy = \int_1^x 3y^{-4}\; dy$$